# Sort a list when one entry has multiple properties?

Tags: c#

Im trying to figure out, how to sort a List in C# by one value. Each entry of the list has a name, a date time and a second number. How can i sort that by the date time?

Comment: Did you search before asking? "Order list by attribute" should give you plenty of examples.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```
var sortedList = initialList.OrderBy(item => item.DateTimeField).ToList();
```

p.s: use OrderBy or OrderByDescending depending on what order type you want(asc/desc)

Comment: yeah, you're right. I edited, and now it is a list

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Answer (score 0):

I assume the list contains elements of a custom class? In that case your class should implement [IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.8).

Example

```
class MyClass : IComparable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is DateTime otherTimestamp)
        {
            return this.Timestamp.CompareTo(otherTimestamp);
        }

        return 0;  // If obj  is not a DateTime or is null, return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: implementing `IComparable` (or `IComparable<T>`) is *one way* to solve this; by no means the only; `List<T>` has a `Sort` method that accepts ad-hoc comparers, for example, or there's all of LINQ to play with; neither of which makes your type do something just because you want it sorted in a particular way in *one place*. It only makes sense to implement `IComparable[<T>]` if that is a **natural and obvious** unambiguous semantic meaning to "sort these items"

Comment: @MarcGravell Good comment. I just wanted to show _one_ way of achieving his goal. Not sure it is the right one. He will decide for himself.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled